# Mac Mini won't boot past Apple logo and progress bar after having to do a hard boot

Tags: startup, mac-mini

I've had ongoing issues with a Mac Mini ever since an Apple update at the beginning of last week.

Basically, it stops sending a signal to monitor so I can't see anything and then I have to hard boot by holding the power button until it shuts off but when I turn it back on, this happens:-

1. If I just try to power back on normally, it does not send signal to monitor so I have no idea what it is doing and eventually have to keep hard boot again.
2. If I power back on when holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> key to try and go into safe mode, it just displays the Apple logo with progress bar which gets very close to the end or to the end and then it loses signal to monitor again (remains powered on but again, I can't see anything on the screen). It takes a very long time to reach the end of the progress bar. I do not see any safe mode.

I took the Mac Mini to an Apple IT specialist who had it for a day and then told me it was fixed, only a quick fix and "now it's booting fine". After collecting it, I tried to boot it normally (thunderbolt to VGA connection but an old monitor) and I got no signal still so I thought the issue must be my set up, so I plugged in an HDMI cable to one of my main modern monitors and I got the signal, logged in and started playing music via the Deezer app but after a few hours, the Mac became unresponsive (I left it for many hours to see if it would become responsive again) and in the end, I had to hard boot again and then I was back to square one (one of the two points above).

I'm now tackling this again so I've hard booted the Mac Mini, plugging in via HDMI to the decent monitor that is modern and know works without issue. I held down <kbd>shift</kbd> while powering back on and once again, got Apple logo with progress bar which took a long time to reach the end.

[image: Apple logo with progress bar at boot]

When it got to 100% (as in, it visually looks like it is - photo above was taken before it got to the end), it just sits there for a long time (in fact, it's still showing on the screen now and it's been about 30 minutes - surprisingly, the monitor would usually have lost signal by now).

Throughout all of this, I've tried various things online including:-

1. Booting into safe mode.
2. Resetting NVRAM and PRAM.
3. Booting into macOS Recovery System.

Nothing I try seems to make a difference. If I do get a signal to monitor, every time, it just displays the Apple logo with progress bar that takes an age to reach the end and then back to no signal.

The problem I have though as well is that I don't have a Mac keyboard connected, only a standard Windows ones so I'm not entirely sure if I'm even getting the equivalent keyboard strokes correct at boot.

I'm reluctant to go back to the IT repair shop as I think the same thing will just happen so I'm keen to try and get to the bottom of this myself.

**Could anyone advise what I can try or ask me to do something and feed back the outcome in order for someone to pinpoint the issue and get this fixed once and for all.**

If it is of any use:-

- There appears to be no issue at all with the device itself powering on/off.
- There is no unusual sounds or noises coming from the device itself and I hear the power on chime as expected.
- I'm now testing with known working hardware configuration (HDMI direct from device to working modern high resolution monitor).
- I'm not really bothered if anything has to be rolled back or data erased.
- I am unable to confirm the current macOS installed as I can't get it to the login screen but I think it was macOS Catalina.

---

## Edit 4th June 2020

Finally got a chance to try the [comment by Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392474/mac-mini-wont-boot-past-apple-logo-and-progress-bar-after-having-to-do-a-hard-b#comment538897_392474) and for the first time, by holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd> (Windows key) + <kbd>R</kbd> at boot, I have finally managed to get something else to come up which looks like the below macOS Utilities:-

[image: macOS Utilities]

---

## Edit 4th June 2020

Disk utilities and performing first aid on the disk ran successfully and found no problems so I attempted to reinstall macOS (Mojave) on the disk and would not let me select the disk and produced the following error:

```
This disk has SMART errors.

This disk has a hardware problem that can't be repaired. Back up as much of the data as possible and replace the disk.
```

[image: macOs reinstall failing due to hard disk SMART error]

So looks like I am finally getting somewhere and I'm assuming the hard drive is screwed and needs replacing...(?)

Comment: Just to update, I still have the Apple logo with full progress bar on the monitor screen via HDMI and several hours have now passed so it clearly won't progress past this point.

Comment: Boot into [Verbose Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) (`Cmd-V` while booting).  This will give you all the boot messages so you can see where it hangs. Also try booting into Internet Recovery (`Opt-Cmd-R`). If you can’t boot there, there’s an issue with your hardware.

Comment: @Allan Excellent, please see my edit above, I have managed to get up macOS Utilities from booting up holding CMD + R - please let me know what I should now do with the options this presents?

Comment: I've checked disk utility and performed the first aid function on the disk. It "appeared to be okay" so no problems found.

Comment: I'm actually just trying to reinstall macOS (Mojave) now so will update once this has completed.

Comment: See further update above - can't reinstall macOS as the disk has SMART errors - I am assuming now, at this stage, there is nothing I can do other than have the hard drive replaced?

Comment: That is correct.  Even if you were able to get the OS to install, it’s on a drive that’s failing so its going to crash in the near future.  You’ve got to replace the drive.  The good news is, you can replace the mini’s hard disk with an SSD and boost it’s performance significantly.

Comment: Already got it booked in somewhere for a new SSD to be fitted replacing the current disk. Thanks for all your help @Allan - happy to mark as accepted answer if you wanted to add one.

Comment: I’ll type up an answer as soon as I get back to my computer.  :-)